# Emacs calc minibuffer blank face---how to debug?

Tags: emacs, initialization, calc

When running emacs calc, typing a prefix key, say 'm', followed by '?' is supposed to show all mode-related commands in the minibuffer as a kind of quick help facility.

For several years I have noticed that this quit working for me.  When I hit the '?' the minibuffer flashes the help for a small fraction of a second, then goes blank.  I can sometimes see parts of the help text rendered but ususally it blanks too fast to see it.

This does not happen when I run emacs -Q to skip my init file, so it is something in the init file that is the cuplprit.

My init file is quite large.  I would like to put something like '(exit)' in different places in my init file to stop processing the init file and see if I can pin down what is causing the problem.

(1) What is the right way to do this?

(2) Anybody else see this problem with the minibuffer in calc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of trying to narrow down the problem, I found the culprit.

When key-chord-mode is set on in calc, the key help facility displays the symptoms I mentioned above.

Would like to keep key-chord enabled globally and disable it in calc-mode, but turning it off in the calc-mode-hook turns it off for all modes.  Any ideas?

Anyway, I am closer to figuring out this long-term irritant.

Comment: I would contact the key-chord maintainer, personally - unless you find an answer easily.

Comment: Contacted the maintainer, but he had not ready fix.  Would be nice if there were a hook that would fire when the `calc` window get the focus, then I could just toggle off `keychord-mode` then without turning it off globally.

Comment: This has been happening for me too.  It would be nice to have a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. The answer is simple: **recursively bisect your init file**.

Do that by commenting out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, then 7/8,... This is a binary search, and it is very quick, even though it might not seem that way at first. It is systematic, and essentially blind (thoughtless).

To comment out a block of text, use command `comment-region`. To uncomment a block of text, use `C-u` with the same command.

Trust me - in no time at all, you will have identified the culprit code, no matter how big your init file is. And if you load other libraries from your init file, and doing the exercise above shows that the culprit code is in one of those libraries, then do the same thing with (a copy of) that library code: recursively bisect it.

Comment: Drew, thanks.  I did the bisection and have narrowed it down to one of the elpa packages.  Since those appear to be auto-required, is my only option to uninstall the packages one at a time, or can you think of something better.

Comment: Dunno - I'm no expert on package.el. Try just putting (a copy of) the library's files in your `load-path` and `require` the library. You can modify the copy to comment-out parts etc., to bisect it - just like you did your init file. Alternatively, contact the library owner/author/maintainer.  Oops - I see now that you already located the problem.